# JUnit5 Gradle plugin overrides the default build task

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, plugins, junit5

I'm using the JUnit 5 Gradle plugin as explained here:
http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle

I added the following parts to my `gradle.build` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    // ... some others...
}

apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.0.3'
    testRuntime group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.0.3'
}
```

With the above, when I use the gradle `build` task - I have the following output:

```
Executing task 'build'...

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar
:findMainClass
:startScripts UP-TO-DATE
:distTar
:distZip
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:junitPlatformTest UP-TO-DATE
:test SKIPPED
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Since this includes `junitPlatformTest` I assume that the plugin overrides the regular `build` task. I would like to know if there's any way to avoid this behavior.

Comment: The JUnit5 Gradle plugin just adds the `junitPlatformTest` task as task dependency of the `build` lifecycle task.

Comment: @lu.koerfer I want to keep some setups without running tests at all (i.e. a Jenkins environment where I only call the tasks "clean build"). Is that something I can achieve while keeping the plugin defined in the code?

Comment: How about just running the lifecycle task `assemble`?

Comment: If you want to exclude execution of a task in Gradle, you simply supply the `-x` flag. For example: `gradle -x junitPlatformTest clean build`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin does not override the `build` task. It adds a dependency from the `test` task to the `junitPlatformTest` task and (by default) disables the standard `test` task (to avoid executing JUnit 4-based tests multiple times).

`build` depends on `check` and `assemble`, `check` depends on `test` (see [Gradle User Manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#_lifecycle_tasks)). Thus, when you execute `build`, `junitPlatformTest` will be executed as in your example.